# forever ignoring killSignal

Tags: node.js, forever

I've been using `forever` in a service script successfully for a while now. I'm attempting to deploy a zero-downtime configuration, and the only missing piece for me is that `forever` seems to be ignoring the `--killSignal` parameter. The relevant part of my service script is:

`daemon --user=$user \
      $forever --killSignal=SIGHUP -p $forever_dir --uid $uid --pidFile $pidfile -l $logfile \
      -a --sourceDir $SOURCE_DIR start $SOURCE_FILE &`

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? I've looked at forever's code and read the documentation, and it seems others are using it successfully. I've tried the `killSignal` switch as `killSignal=SIGHUP` and `killSignal SIGHUP` but neither seem to make any difference; it's still sending `SIGKILL`.

Edit: for the record, it also seems to be ignoring the `pidFile` argument.

Answer (score 2):

I had some issues with forever using the killsignal and killttl options, plus restarting my script the way I wanted. I ended up writing my own supervisor script using [forever-monitor](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor):

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor'),
    child = createChild();

process.on('SIGUSR2', function restart() {
    // This signal is used to restart gracefully.
    var newChild = createChild();
    child.stop();
    child = newChild;
});

process.on('SIGTERM', function stop() {
    child.stop();
    child.on('stop', function () {
        process.exit();
    });
});

function createChild() {
    console.log('Running a new instance');
    var child = new (forever.Monitor)(__dirname + '/main.js', {
        killTTL : 50000,
        killSignal : 'SIGTERM'
    });
    child.on('stop', function () {
        console.log('Old instance has stopped');
    });
    child.on('exit:code', console.log.bind(console, 'Old instance has exitted with code'))
    child.on('error', function (error) {
        console.error(error.stack || error);
    });
    return child.start();
}
```

You can use this as an example. You can add the pidFile option here too.